# Returning part of a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring

In SQL Server how do I return part of a string? the data is not fixed however the number of characters is and its position in the string. for example I want to just return the N Prefix code that is 10 characters...

```
000010000100001LN000002496 00000 0496139796000000001101GOODS IN RM CHECK 003
```

Comment: If you'd google, you'd probably find `substring`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUBSTRING is your friend:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100)='000010000100001LN000002496 00000 0496139796000000001101GOODS IN RM CHECK 003';

SELECT SUBSTRING(@string,1,10);
```

The result

```
0000100001
```

Find details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

Comment: Many thanks Shnugo, this has worked perfectly! apologies for the unclear question, im very new to report writing and this was my first question. regards...

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below generalized code which will get the data based on the position of the N.

```
declare @find varchar(100)='000010000100001LN000002496 00000    0496139796000000001101GOODS'

print  LEFT(SUBSTRING (@find,1,charindex('N',@find,1)-1),10)
```

if you remove the LEFT function in the above sql, then it will give the complete prefix of the N in the string data.